# Solving large-scale nonlinear system using exact Newton's method in SciPy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve a large-scale nonlinear system using the exact Newton method in SciPy. In my application, the Jacobian is easy to assemble (and factorize) as a sparse matrix.

It seems that all methods available in `scipy.optimize.root` approximate the Jacobian in one way or another, and I can't find a way to use Newton's method using the API that is discussed in [SciPy's  documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

Nonetheless, using the internal API, I have managed to use Newton's method with the following code:

```
from scipy.optimize.nonlin import nonlin_solve
x, info = nonlin_solve(f, x0, jac, line_search=False)
```

where `f(x)` is the residual and `jac(x)` is a callable that returns the Jacobian at `x` as a sparse matrix.

However, I am not sure whether this function is meant to be used outside SciPy and is subject to changes without notice.

Would this be recommended approach?

Answer (score 1):

It is meant to be used.

Scipy's private functions that are not meant to be used from the outside start with a `_`.

This was confirmed by the scipy's team in an issue I raised recently: cf https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17510